# dump Mysql tables in centos server by using php code ...?

Tags: php, centos, mysql

I am running  one application in centos server.

I am trying to make dumping(BackUp) one table to folder

1st Example :

```
<?php
  $cmd = "passwd";
  echo exec($cmd,$arr);
  print_r($arr);
?>
```

Output is :

```
 Changing password for apache.
 Array
(
     [0] => Changing password for user apache.
     [1] => Changing password for apache.
)
```

But While using mysqldump command i am getting empty array as a result

```
<?php
  $cmd = "mysqldump -u root db_name table_name > /var/path/file.csv";
  echo exec($cmd,$arr);
  print_r($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is not working?? DETAILS! What's the error message? Maybe exec() is disabled?

Comment: what the content of ``$arr``?

Comment: While running the above script there is no response...
And How to enable exec()...

Comment: I am Getting the Empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?PHP
 $cmd = "mysqldump -u root db_name table_name > /var/path/filename.sql";
 echo shell_exec($cmd);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be password issue. Please try following code:

```
 <?PHP
 $cmd = "mysqldump --u root --p password db_name table_name > /var/path/filename.sql";
 echo shell_exec($cmd);
 ?>
```